# Writing Java Kafka consumer application without `while` loop

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We recently started to use Kafka and I am writing a Kafka consumer application using Kafka Java native consumer API.

However most of the examples I saw are using a `while` loop and then call `poll` method on a consumer object in the loop. Like below:

```
while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords =
                    consumer.poll(1000);

            if (consumerRecords.count()==0) {
                noRecordsCount++;
                if (noRecordsCount > giveUp) break;
                else continue;
            }

            consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
                System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n",
                        record.key(), record.value(),
                        record.partition(), record.offset());
            });

            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
```

I am just seeking a better way of doing this without a loop using the native Java consumer API. I know by using spring kafka you don't need to write those. How about using native API? Any good approach or best practice?

Comment: *doing this without a loop* - I don't see how you can consume 24/7 without a loop. It needs to be more sofisticated than a while(true), yes, but you need it anyway, if you want to use native api and not fancy-callback-frameworks or some lambda-magic. The loop should be controlled by a monitor or some other structure that catches termination signals (SIGTERM,..), instead of being a infinite while true. Do not loop conditioned on kafka's poll method, since you could have moments without messages, which doesn't mean you have to stop consuming (just sleep a little bit)

Comment: theoretically you could use a scheduled job running every second to achieve the same..if you don't like loops

Comment: There are other Kafka libraries than Spring that also don't require an explicit loop. https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/#_retrieving_messages_from_kafka

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a scheduler and code is working.

```
 package com.kafka;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
 Date now; // to display current time
    public void run( ) {
        now = new Date();
    System.out.println("Time is :" + now);
    String AlarmString=null;
    Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.*.*.*:9092");
     props.put("group.id", "grp-1");
     props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
     props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
     props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
     props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
     consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("RAW_MH_RAN_SAM"));
    
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
        //ConsumerRecords<String, String> records =consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
         {
             
             System.out.println("Consumer:=============== partition Id= " + record.partition() + "  offset = " + record.offset() + " value = " + record.value() + "=================");
             
             if (AlarmString==null && !(record.value().toString().contains("PR ALARM:")) ){
                 
                 AlarmString=record.value(); 
                 
                }
             else{
                    if( !(record.value().toString().contains("PR ALARM:"))   )
                    
                    {
                        //System.out.println("record.value()   :::"+ record.value() );  
                        AlarmString=AlarmString+","+record.value();
                            
                    }
                    
                }
        
         }
     if (consumer != null) {
         System.out.println("Closing Connection");
         consumer.close();
      }
    
 }


}
//Simple consumer 
package com.kafka;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Timer;
public class SimpleConsumer{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    
    Timer time = new Timer();
    ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
    time.schedule(st, 0,60000); // Create Repetitively task for every 1 secs  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Polling continuously is "just" the way how Kafka consumer works, how the underneath Kafka protocol works.
Each action is always initiated by the clients (pulling model) not by brokers (pushing model) that in case of consuming messages translates into polling.
Using the Java Kafka consumer API means having a loop, using a scheduler or whatever technology you have with Java for executing code continuously, you have to deal with it.
Other frameworks like Spring or Smallrye reactive messaging just do that for you. They are hiding the poll loop to your application but in the end there is always a loop ... it's how Kafka works.